# How do I get a SystemTime from a human-readable date format in a cross-platform way? (Rust)

Tags: datetime, rust, cross-platform

How would I convert a human readable time (in any format, such as `Tue, 1 Jul 2003 10:52:37 +0200`) into a [`SystemTime`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.SystemTime.html), in a cross-platform way? I know about [`chrono::DateTime::from_rfc2822()`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#method.parse_from_rfc2822), but I've been searching for quite a while and I can't find a way to convert a `DateTime` into a `SystemTime`. This conversion also needs to be cross-platform, so I can't use the platform-specific epochs (such as [`UNIX_EPOCH`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/constant.UNIX_EPOCH.html#)).

Does anyone have any advice or ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I dont quite understand why would you need SystemTime. Can you provide an specific example. This maybe an x/y problem.

Comment: @Netwave The reason I need a `SystemTime` is so that I can change the modification times of some files. I need to have the date start in a human-readable format, so I can make sure that a sorting algorithm gets `year/month/` directories right when sorting by modification time. I decided not to provide a [example] because I thought that the question would be clear enough without it, and besides, my code would probably be too long for Stack Overflow.

Comment: btw `UNIX_EPOCH` is a constant, it is not platfrom specific.

Comment: @Netwave `UNIX_EPOCH`, when used to get the modification time of a file, _is_ platform-specific. I couldn't use `UNIX_EPOCH` to accurately get the modification time of a file on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [conversion available](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/src/chrono/datetime.rs.html#780) for `DateTime<Tz>` to `SystemTime`, so you just need to call `.into()`:

```
let system_time: SystemTime = DateTime::parse_from_rfc2822("Tue, 1 Jul 2003 10:52:37 +0200").unwrap().into();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=38efd50a8edab257b7aa888169a2c0e6)